# jquery how to combine two selectors to second function of single toggle event

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a regular toggle function bound to a click event

```
$('#work-content a').toggle(
    function() {
        // first click stuff
    }, function() {
        // second click stuff
    }
);
```

But, I also need to bind `$(document).click` event to the second function somehow. My logic is probably off so I'm sure a new solution is necessary.

Functionality is 1) do something when link is clicked then 2) do the opposite when the link is clicked again or if the outside of the `#work-content` div is clicked.

Comment: I'm confused. You want the same toggle bond to both the document and `#work-content a`? Or one toggle for one and one for when clicking off `#work-content`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
linkClicked = false;    
$('#work-content .pic a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var c = $(this);

    if (!linkClicked) {
        values = workOpen($(this));
    } else {
        workClose(c, values);
    }

    $('body').one('click',function() {
        workClose(c, values);
    });

});
```

This solution was exactly what I needed for what it's worth.

Answer (score 1):

Just extract the anonymous function and give it a name:

```
var thatFunction = function () {
    ...
}

$('#work-content a').toggle(
    function() {
        // first click stuff
    },
    thatFunction);

$(document).click(thatFunction);
```

Answer (score 1):

the toggle function is used to hide/show your div and should not be used to maintain state of an event. just use another local variable for this and also define two functions perform your two different actions and pass the function pointer as callback to your event listener.

thus:

```
var linkClicked=false;

function fun1(){}

function fun2(){}

$('#work-content a').click(
    function() {
        if(!linkClicked)
          fun1();
        else
          fun2();
    });
$("body").click(function(){
  if($(event.target).closest("#work-content")===null)  //to make sure clicking inside your div does not trigger its close
  {
    fun2();
  }
});
```